# Placing a "protocol" field in the IP header breaks the conceptual separation of interests that the OSI aimed for

Tags: ip, osi

I saw that while reading an answer about .. and now I'm confused.

Comment: And what is your question? Keep in mind that OSI is a theoretical model which is not used anywhere. In practice we use the TCP/IP model which is similar but quite different.

Comment: This is a matter of definition, opinion or taste and therefore off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it leads to pointless arguing.

Answer (score 1):

As JFL says, OSI is a *theoretical* model, and nothing in the real world follows it.

But, what you suggest doesn't actually break the model. All the protocol field does is to tell IP to which registered process to send the payload of the IP packet. The Protocol field of IPv4 (Next Header field of IPv6) is simply a number of a process which registered for that number. That doesn't mean that IP knows anything about the process or payload of the packet.